# Induction on the number of edges $(-1)^wI(G)\leq (-1)^w\sum_{i=0}^w(-1)^ig_i.$

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I need help with this theorem about graph theory. In Some Graph Theoretic Results Associated with Ramsey's Theorem of Graver and Yackel find this proposition 5.

---

Proposition 5: Let $G$ be a graph with girth $z$ and let $g_i$ be the number of connected subgraphs of $G$ with $i$ edges. Then for all integers $w < z$,
$$(-1)^wI(G)\leq (-1)^w\sum_{i=0}^w(-1)^ig_i.$$
Equality will hold if $G$ is circuit free and the summation is over all connected subgraphs.

---

$I(G)$, is the maximum number of points of $G$ that can be chosen so that no two are joined by an edge. (size of a maximum independence set).

The girth is the length of a shortest cycle contained in the graph. If the graph does not contain any cycles (i.e. it's an acyclic graph), its girth is defined to be infinity

A circuit is path that begins and ends at the same vertex

---

OK, They proceed by induction on the number of edges in the graph

**Induction Hypothesis**. Let $G$ be a graph with girth greater than $w$, and $p$ be a point of $G$. There exists a partition of the connected subgraphs of $G$ with $w$ or fewer edges into two classes, the subgraphs of one class will be said to be positive and those of the second class negative. For $i=0,1,\cdots , w-1$ there exist functions $f_i : S_i^+ \to S_{i+1}^-$ (where $S_j^+$ is the
set of positive subgraphs with $j$ edges and $S_j^-$ is the set of negative subgraphs with $j$ edges). Also the following conditions are satisfied

**1)** $S_o^-$ is a maximum independent set;

**2)** if the point $p \in S_o^-$ then $p$ is essential in $G$;

**3)** $f_i$ is one to one and onto for $i= 1, 2,\cdots, w - 1$ ;

**4)** for all positive subgraphs $H$ with fewer than $w$ edges, $p$ is a point
of $H$ iff $p$ is a point of $f_i(H)$;

**5)** if $G$ has $w$ or fewer edges then $S_w^+ = \emptyset$.

note that the induction hypothesis is satisfied for all graphs having no edges. Finally, if $G$ is a graph which satisfies the induction hypothesis for some point $p$, then $G$ with any isolated point added will also satisfy the hypothesis (conditions $(2)$ and $(4)$ being trivially satisfied for any isolated point).

---

If the hypothesis says that $G$ be a graph with girth greater than $w$, how condition $5$ works?

---

TRY

When $z=\infty$, proposition is fulfilled.

what would happen if $z = 3$, I try to define the function
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

how could I define $S_0^-$, so that the function remains bijective and meets condition $1$ and $2$.

Because the proof is doing the induction on the number of points  $n$, it would not be more convenient to do it on the girth $z$.

How condition $5$  is working ? If the hypothesis says that $G$ be a graph with girth greater than $w$.

I would appreciate any comment.

---

sometimes I think I'm misunderstanding the proposition!!